# PHP Error: Call to undefined function saveimage

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE){
            $first_ul_status = "Please select an image";
        }else{
            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image);
            saveimage($name,$image);
        }
        function saveimage($name,$image){
            $first_ul_query = "UPDATE `users` SET `Photo Name`='$name',`Photo`='$image' WHERE `ID`='$UserSession'";
            $first_ul_result = mysql_query($first_ul_query);
            if($first_ul_result){
                $first_ul_status = "Image uploaded";
            }else{
                $first_ul_status = "Image not uploaded";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

I just got this code from the web I don't remember where I got this code. But I have the video tutorial of this thats why I have this code right now. 
Last time this code is working to me but now my problem is that I cant call the saveimage($name,$image);

Can somebody help me out there? Thanks in advance pros :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure your *saveimage()* function is declared when call that. Put the function forward in your code as you call!

Answer (score 3):

You added function within the script..I have fixed it..the function is out of the code now. It is an independent snippet now, you can call it now..

```
<?php
require('config.php');


 function saveimage($name,$image){
        $first_ul_query = "UPDATE `users` SET `Photo Name`='$name',`Photo`='$image' WHERE `ID`='$UserSession'";
        $first_ul_result = mysql_query($first_ul_query);
        if($first_ul_result){
            $first_ul_status = "Image uploaded";
        }else{
            $first_ul_status = "Image not uploaded";
        }
    }


if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE){
        $first_ul_status = "Please select an image";
    }else{
        $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image = file_get_contents($image);
        $image = base64_encode($image);
        saveimage($name,$image);
    }

}


 ?>
```

Comment: still cant Fatal error: Call to undefined function saveimage()

Comment: a quick fix...replace the  saveimage($name,$image); with the code within the function.. try then.

Comment: still cant. i tried to remove and separate but nothing happen, still same error

Comment: what the error..if you remove saveimage.,,it wont work

Comment: no error but can't save if i'll remove the saveimage()

Comment: now that is another issue.. you can try like print_r($_POST); to see the array that gets posted there..

Comment: if i remove the call function theres no error but when i remove the function saveimage(){} I will get the same error :(